# Convert UTF8 to int16 in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, websocket

I read a binary file (of 16bit integers) in my node.js code and send it to client using connection.sendUTF(data) of websocket. At the javascript code of the client side I receive an array of UTF8 and would like to convert back every pair to an int16 ( numbers are unsigned, if makes it simple).

I came up with this function to be used at the client side and was wondering if it is correct.

```
function char2BigEndian16(hiChar, lowChar){
    return  ((lowChar.charCodeAt(0)& 0x00FF) << 8) | (hiChar.charCodeAt(0) & 0xFF);
}
```

and here is how I call it to convert first to elements of array data to a 2-byte integer

```
 var  i16 = char2BigEndian16(data[1], data[0]);
```

If this help here is my node.js code snipped:

```
var fs = require('fs');
    filename = "test.txt";
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error!!');
                return console.log(err);
            }
        connection.sendUTF(data);

        });
```

and here is how I deal with the received data on the client side

```
connection.onmessage = function(e) {
                console.log(e.data.length);
}
```

Comment: X Y problem detected - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work reliably. An UTF-8 file isn't a bunch of distinct 8-bit values, each character can use one or more bytes. When you read the file as UTF-8, some values will be interpreted as multi-byte groups and be converted into a single character. You can only reliably read a file as UTF-8 that actually was created as an UTF-8 text file.

You need to read the file without an encoding, so that you get back the data unchanged:

```
fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
```

Now you can send the data to the client, and each byte will be a byte from the original file.

Comment: Hmm, good points.  Could OP use String.fromCharCode() to create a UCS-2 encoded string and send *that* via sendUTF?  ('Not sure if surrogate  the surrogate ranges come into play here though.)

Seems like he should either do that or use `sendBytes()` to send the raw data.

Comment: @broofa: Well, sending bytes as UTF-16 would maybe work, but then the stream gets twice as big as the original file, and still needs decoding on the client side to patch 8-bit values (converted from 16-bit character codes) into 16-bit values.

Comment: I would assume that the server-side `sendUTF` API would convert the JS UCS-2 string to UTF8.  And since this is sent as a UTF8 string, I assume it would manifest as a [JS UCS-2] String in the websocket `message` event - i.e. OP wouldn't have to do anything special to decode other than `messageData.charCodeAt(someIndex)` to get each int16 value.  No?

Comment: @broofa: You mean reading the file as UCS-2 although it's not a text file at all, and sending it as text... Sounds like there could be several ways that the data gets corrupted, like for example character code normalizing.

Comment: @Guffa I just added the code snipped of client side where I want to use the revived data. However, for some reason I get error below when I call console.log(e.data.length); "TypeError: RIdata.length is not a function " I used your solution both with sendBytes and sendUTF. Any suggestion why its happening?

Comment: @c: I have hard to find documentation about that... what websocket implementation are you using?

Comment: @Guffa e.data is a Blob does that help?

Comment: @Cgraphics: I came to the same conclusion. If it doesn't have a `length` it has to be a Blob, and has a `size` instead. You can use a `FileReader` to read from the `Blob`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: @Gufa I am not yet familiar with the Blob's fileds. What field should I use to access the data here?e.data.getValues did not work. Please let me know what field the client needs to use to access the data contents. Thanks

Comment: @Cgraphics: There is an example on the page that I linked to on how to use a `FileReader` object to read from the Blob. According to that page, that is the only way to get the data out of the Blob.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Guffa, you're probably starting out with bad data.   If your data file is a raw binary file of 16-bit values, then reading that as UTF8 encoded text is pretty much guaranteed to fail.  Instead, omit the `encoding` argument so you get a Buffer of binary data on the server side, and use websocket's `sendBytes` method to transmit it as raw data.

On the client side your websocket's message event should then provide a `data` property that is a ArrayBuffer (or possibly a `Blob`) of binary data, which you could then convert to int16 values via something like ...

```
function arrayByteToInt16(byteArray) {
  var ints = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i += 2) {
    // Note: assuming Big-Endian here
    ints.push((byteArray[i] << 8) | (byteArray[i+1]));
  }
  return ints;
}
```

[Edit: complete rewrite of answer]

Comment: For some reason giving "e.data" as input to this function would all return 0! as well e.data.length return error ( e.data.lengh is not a function)!